# No data saved in the partial view

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to save data updated on the partial view called in parent Edit action. But the updated data is not saved.

I have a parent table 'Nz' and a child one 'Mkh' and trying to retrieve all the data of it in 'Nz' edit action as a partial view to let the user update it.
The data is retrieved correctly but when the user update the data and press submit no data is saved!
on the other hand, I want to retrieve 'Select' items with returned values not a normal text item.

This is my code:

```
//Nz model:
    public partial class Nz
    {
        public Nz()
        {
            Mkh = new HashSet<Mkh>();
        }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#########}")]
        public decimal TxtId { get; set; }
        public int Sn { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        public int SexCode { get; set; }
        public string InsertUser { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Mkh> Mkh { get; set; }
    }
//Mkh Model:
    public partial class Mkh
    {
        public int Sn { get; set; }
        public decimal TxtId { get; set; }
        public int MkhCode { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime MkhDate { get; set; }
        public int Days { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string InsertUser { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }


        public MkhType MkhCodeNavigation { get; set; }
        public Nz Txt { get; set; }
    }
//MkhType Model:
    public partial class MkhType
    {
        public MkhType()
        {
            Mkh = new HashSet<Mkh>();
        }

        public int MkhCode { get; set; }
        public string MkhName { get; set; }
        public string InsertUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Mkh> Mkh { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my context:

```
public partial class NozContext : DbContext
{
    public NozContext()
    {
    }

    public NozContext(DbContextOptions<NozContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Mkh> Mkh { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MkhType> MkhType { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Nz> Nz { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Sex> Sex { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=My-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Noz;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Mkh>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Sn);

            entity.ToTable("Mkh");

            entity.Property(e => e.Sn).HasColumnName("sn");

            entity.Property(e => e.Days).HasColumnName("days");

            entity.Property(e => e.InsertDate)
                .HasColumnName("insert_date")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.InsertUser)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("insert_user")
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(N'any')");

            entity.Property(e => e.MkhCode).HasColumnName("Mkh_code");

            entity.Property(e => e.MkhDate)
                .HasColumnName("Mkh_date")
                .HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.Notes).HasColumnName("notes");

            entity.Property(e => e.TxtId)
                .HasColumnName("txt_id")
                .HasColumnType("numeric(9, 0)");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.MkhCodeNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Mkh)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MkhCode)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Mkh_Mkh_type");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Txt)
                .WithMany(p => p.Mkh)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.TxtId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Mkh_Nz");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MkhType>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.MkhCode);

            entity.ToTable("Mkh_type");

            entity.Property(e => e.MkhCode).HasColumnName("Mkh_code");

            entity.Property(e => e.InsertDate)
                .HasColumnName("insert_date")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.InsertUser)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("insert_user")
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(N'any')");

            entity.Property(e => e.MkhName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("Mkh_name")
                .HasMaxLength(50);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Nz>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.TxtId);

            entity.ToTable("Nz");

            entity.Property(e => e.TxtId)
                .HasColumnName("txt_id")
                .HasColumnType("numeric(9, 0)");

            entity.Property(e => e.BirthDate)
                .HasColumnName("birth_date")
                .HasColumnType("date");


            entity.Property(e => e.InsertDate)
                .HasColumnName("insert_date")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.InsertUser)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("insert_user")
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(N'any')");

            entity.Property(e => e.SexCode).HasColumnName("sex_code");

            entity.Property(e => e.Sn)
                .HasColumnName("sn")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.SexCodeNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Nz)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SexCode)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Nz_sex");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Sex>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.SexCode);

            entity.ToTable("sex");

            entity.Property(e => e.SexCode).HasColumnName("sex_code");

            entity.Property(e => e.SexName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("sex_name")
                .HasMaxLength(10);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Nz>()
        .HasAlternateKey(x => x.Sn).HasName("IX_Sn");
    }
}
```

and the NzController actions:

```
public class NzController : Controller
{
    private readonly NozContext _context;

    public NzController(NozContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
// ........ Some Code here .............
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(decimal? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        //var Nz = await _context.Nz.FindAsync(id);
        var Nz = await _context.Nz
                     .Include(n => n.Mkh)
                     .ThenInclude(m => m.MkhCodeNavigation)
                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(n => n.TxtId == id.Value);
        if (Nz == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["SexCode"] = new SelectList(_context.Sex, "SexCode", "SexName", Nz.SexCode);
        return View(Nz);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(decimal id, [Bind("TxtId,Sn,FullName,BirthDate,SexCode,InsertUser,InsertDate")] Nz Nz)
    {
        if (id != Nz.TxtId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var Edited = new Nz()
                {
                    TxtId = Nz.TxtId,
                    BirthDate = Nz.BirthDate,
                    InsertDate = Nz.InsertDate,
                    InsertUser = Nz.InsertUser,
                    FullName = Nz.FullName,
                    SexCode = Nz.SexCode,
                    Mkh = Nz.Mkh.Where(m => m.TxtId == Nz.TxtId).ToList(),
                };
                _context.Update(Edited);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!NzExists(Nz.TxtId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["SexCode"] = new SelectList(_context.Sex, "SexCode", "SexName", Nz.SexCode);
        return View(Nz);
    }
```

the partial view 'EditNz':

```
@model IEnumerable<Mkh>

<h4>MkhTbl</h4>
<hr />
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Days
                </th>
                <th>
                    Notes
                </th>
                <th>
                    Mkh Type
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.MkhDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Days)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Notes)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.MkhCodeNavigation.MkhName)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    @section Scripts {
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    }
```

and the calling of the previous partial in Edit view in NzController:

```
@model NozCoreWebApp5.Models.Nz
@*@{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    }*@

<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="TxtId" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="InsertDate" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="InsertUser" />

    <hr />


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label asp-for="FullName" class="control-label">Full Name</label>
            <input asp-for="FullName" class="form-control" readonly/>
            <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label asp-for="BirthDate" class="control-label">Birth Date</label>
            <input asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control" readonly/>
            <span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label asp-for="SexCode" class="control-label">Sex</label>
            <select asp-for="SexCode" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SexCode"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="SexCode" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Nz List</a>
</div>

@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("~/Views/Mkhalfa/EditNz.cshtml", Model.Mkh); }

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Now when I press save button (submit) no data is saved for the partial one like days! Why? and How to solve please?

and How to return Select with returned values from MkhType? (using MkhCodeNavigation I think)

This is what happen when I put a breakpoint in the Edit method at 'Edited' var and trying to update the 'days' field in the partial:
[image: Post Edit Method]

as you notice Edited var is null. does that mean no data passed to the controller? how to solve?

Comment: how are you using the Partial?

Comment: see the code above please. Everything is explained

Comment: can you show the page/view that this partial is loaded into? Also what version of asp.net core mvc are you running?

Comment: have you used a break point at all in the Controller to see if anything is being passed back to the Edit Method?

Comment: I edited the question and added the Edit view which calls the partial at the last.
The version is .net core 2.1.

Comment: Move the partial to be inside the form... The form controls the data be in sent back to your edit method also you can shorten your partial call with `<partial />` tag helper, it's async by default

Comment: @Musbah What is the need for asynchronous partial view if you are having whole page round trip on save button?

Comment: @mvermef I moved it and replaced the partial call with <partial /> tag helper. But still no data saved! please see the question again I put what I have with breakpoint.

Comment: On the edit method temporarily remove the anti-forgery attribute since the form isn't setup for it, with break point does Nz parameter have anything in it

Comment: @mvermef I removed it. I put a break point at the beginning of the method; id parameter has a value say '8002' and under Nz all of Nz items have values but for Mkh the value is 'Count=0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized what you did....

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(decimal id, [Bind("TxtId,Sn,FullName,BirthDate,SexCode,InsertUser,InsertDate")] Nz Nz)
```

What's missing here is Mkh from the binding list, e.g. not bound not filled.  Hence the empty results. You can keep the binding but need to add in Mkh to the list

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(decimal id, [Bind("TxtId,Sn,FullName,BirthDate,SexCode,Mkh,InsertUser,InsertDate")] Nz Nz)
```

One other thing your current setup doesn't allow for multi-entries into the Mkh collection, except for 1 at a time. Save and repeat, reload page from another Edit. Mkh saves might run into graph issues with EF as well.. But i think you have accounted for it with the relationships that you have setup.

Comment: Thanks you are right, but I've updated the setup by replacing collection to IList and it is working now all data is saved for the parent or the child by one press of submit button